# The DISPLAY environment variable is missing in jupyter

Tags: python-2.7

o3.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd_front_center])

---

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-651a82918774> in <module>
----> 1 o3.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd_front_center])

RuntimeError: [Open3D ERROR] GLFW Error: X11: The DISPLAY environment variable is missing

what is the error in that statement

Comment: The trick here is that it's an X11 problem (or possibly Open3d), not specifically a python problem. On Linux, X11 has been the primary graphics system for a while, to the extent that (I think) the xorg replacement is pretty much compatible.  This error message is about the Open3D library looking for information about how to draw 'stuff' on a display. To do that, it seems to be looking for X11 settings, specifically, an environment variable `DISPLAY` which tells it something about how / where to draw its stuff. So maybe add X11 and Open3D tags? my `DISPLAY` is `:0` FWIW